# How to send a proactive message (adaptive card) to a group of users who are online in Teams using a bot on botframework SDK V4

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Sending a proactive message is not working consistently in Teams. Once bot is installed for the first time proactive message is notified but when tried again with an adaptive card, it is not working and even after reverting it back to message, then also it is not working.

Comment: Hi, and welcome.

Please consider adding more information and a the code you are using.  It's difficult to help without further information.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? Do you want to send message in a group/team where the bot is installed?

Comment: Thanks for the ask. I resolved the issue by saving/storing  the conversation reference in azure blob storage.